# Creating an instruction format for a processor

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, processor, microprocessors

I'm supposed to create an instruction format fo a processor with following details:

- 32 instructions
- 2 address-machine
- word size 32 bit
- 16 registers
- 64 Mwords central memory available
- memory is byte-addressable
- constant are of 1 word-wide
- addressings: directly register, indirectly register, directly storing, immediate, register indicated with 16 bit index

I actually almost know how to do it but I got a few questions about this.

What would be the bit size of 32 instructions? I know that if we had 16 instructions it would be 4. For 32, we would have 8?
Basically, I'm only asking for the bit sizes, and if possible, how to count / know them. How much would the address types / addressings have? 3 bit size?

How much the 64 Mwords? 96 bit size? The rest should be clear I think.

Comment: Hint: log_2(8)=3, log_2(16)=4, log_2(32)=5, ...

Comment: @fukanchik Tyvm for the hint/info!
So it means that 32 instructions got bit size / wide of 5, right?

Comment: This however only refers to the 32 instructions? Or for everything?
And how can you know that? I really need to know it or I have big problems tomorrow... Btw, why you take log to basis 2?

Comment: Basis `2` because bit can only take two values, so `n` bits would be enough to represent `2*2...*2=2^n` possible values. Consequently to find out how many bits you need to represent `x` values from `0` to `x-1` you need `log_2(x)`

Comment: This counts for the 32 instructions. How could you do it for addressings or the other stuff? :D
Ty for answer with 2 it makes big sense now.

Comment: Same for all other parts of the structure. For example: you have 5 addressings. ceil(log_2(5))=3, Hence you need at least 3 bits for addressings.